# Change DNS On Pace V2500 Router

Tags: router, dns, telnet, vdsl

I'm trying to change the DNS settings on my Pace V2500 router. There are no settings options within the admin interface so I will have to use telnet to make the changes.

I cannot change the DNS  per device, as some don't allow configuration.

Anybody been successful or know how?

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? There is no manual online for this model. Can you actually telnet into it? If so, can you tell which OS it is running?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the router is re-branded as pace-921vnx. I can login in using telnet. How would I tell which OS it is running? Thanks

Comment: try the command uname. If it does not say `command unknown`, pls tell me its output.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae. It says unknown command : uname

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Busy trying your solution now. Please see comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, I have done the following to configure the router *Pace 921* with a static DNS. I have only done basic testing and still have some issues but it seems to be working for now.

Telnet to the router - I used a Play store app.

The default user name is `admin` and the default password is `nology*/`.

Type the following and remember Linux is case sensitive so use the exact case:

```
cd LANDevice_1_HostConfig
```

If you type `ls` you should only see the local LAN configuration and your prompt should be `LANDevice_1_HostConfig`. Then type:

```
set DHCPServerConfigurable 1
set DNSServers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (your DNS server IP address)
```

Now if you type `ls` you should see the settings you just entered. To save them and quit type:

```
fcommit
quit
```

Then restart your router and the devices connecting to it and check the status of your network connections to see if the DNS has updated.

Now I just need to figure out the syntax to add a secondary server.

I am not 100% sure if you need the `dhcpconfigurable` setting maybe try without it first. Just waiting for my first ISP IP address reset to see if the router keeps the DNS server setting.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this. I was never able to configure the modem before, but I set up a DHCP server and assigned the DNS. I will definitely give this a go! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the rebranding of your router. This did indeed help because I found [the User Manual](http://business.telkom.co.za/enterprise/equipment-devices/data-equipment/modems/pace-921vnx-write-up/downloads/Manual.pdf) here.

We ought to try and change DNS servers from the GUI first. At page 14 I can see this screen:

[image]

which allows configuration of your set-up if you choose: `EoA/IPoA Parameters`. What I suggest you do is: copy your current parameters (you can obtain them by looking at the output of the command `ipconfig` if the router OS is Windows-related, `ifconfig` if it is Unix-related), and then you can copy them into this mask, except for the DNS server for which you ought to choose your own value.

Should this fail, I can tell you how to change DNS servers inside the telnet session only if the OS is Unix-related. In this case, there will be a file /etc/resolv.confwhich you need to edit, as `sudo`, adding two lines that state

```
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
 nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

or which ever DNS server you like (these are Google's).

Comment: Thanks Marius. I really appreciate you looking into this however it wont allow me to update the changes on the EoA/IPoA. The boxes are greyed out. 

I tried to edit the /etc/resolv.conf using vi, No luck.

Available commands are:
fdump
fwork
fbuild
fbuild2
fcommit
frevert
factory
fcompress
applydiff
cd
ls
ln
ping
status
reset
mk
smk
rm
set
sset
get
reboot
quit or exit
upgradefirmware
debug

Comment: This is a guide using telnet that I found. Its just for creating a VPN, You may be able to get more information.

http://residential.telkom.co.za/equipment-devices/broadband-equipment/modems/pace-921vnx-write-up/downloads/VPN_Lite%20_921VNX_Manual.pdf

Comment: There is no obvious way to do it fromwithin telnet. From the GUI, you can update DNSs only if you switch from 'Obtain an IP automatically' to 'Use the following address'. Did you do that before updating DNS servers?

Comment: I cant click on the radio button as its greyed out :(